# Is it possible to edit last item of grid in each rows in nextjs/react and styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, grid, styled-components

I have one grid with auto-fill and many items and I want to edit last item from each column.

Example:

```
<div style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 25rem)">
  <div class="grid-item"> First row item</div>
  <div class="grid-item"> First row item</div>
  <div class="grid-item"> Last item in first row item</div> <- edit this style
  <div class="grid-item"> Second row item</div>
  <div class="grid-item"> Second row item</div>
  <div class="grid-item"> Last item in Second row item</div> <- edit this style
</div>
```

In Next.js with styled-components.

Comment: Are you trying to say, you want to style each last item in every column? Did you try the CSS property ` styled.p 'css here ,&:last-child {
        ....your css
    }'` in your styled components.

Comment: yes. there are two ways to do that in my opinion. first you can make a parent of each row then select last element using JS. second method is by picking a sequence as you can see in your sequence third child is last element of first row then 6th element. you can write a  function that will pick these element then you can do whatever you want